# CPU Scaling governor on tlp

Tags: power-management, battery, cpu

I'm configuring tlp on Ubuntu, and I'm wondering if "powersave" governor will affect my device and not reducing the performance speed.

If it's reducing the performance is it possible to have the performance governor on AC and powersave on BAT, is there any difference?

tlp man says that it's recommended to keep it on powersave no matter on which mode I am.

Comment: It's because powersave moves to performance on demand. Performance always runs at full frequency causing hot laptop and fans at full speed probably.

Comment: So basically if I'm going to swith on performance mode on AC, my laptop will go nuts

Comment: It's easy to turn on performance mode from the terminal. I wrote an answer on that I think. But I'm on phone. Any way turn it on for an hour and warm your hands on keyboard.